# AWS S3 PHP SDK 2 Copy an object to another bucket error 'Bad request' 400

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I need to copy an object from a bucket to another bucket. I try with this code:

```
   $response = $s3->copyObject(
            array(
                'Bucket' => 'ORIGINAL BUCKET',
                'Key' => 'OBJECT KEY',
                'CopySource' => urlencode('ORIGINAL BUCKET' . '/' . 'OBJECT KEY')
            ), array(
                'Bucket' => 'NEW BUCKET',
                'Key' => 'NEW OBJECT KEY',
                'CopySource' => urlencode('NEW BUCKET' . '/' . 'NEW OBJECT KEY')
            )

        );
```

But I get an error type 400 Bad Request:

```
object(Aws\S3\Exception\InvalidRequestException)[274]
  protected 'response' => 
    object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Response)[261]
      protected 'body' => 
        object(Guzzle\Http\EntityBody)[260]
          protected 'contentEncoding' => boolean false
          protected 'rewindFunction' => null 
          protected 'stream' => resource(299, stream)
          protected 'size' => null
          protected 'cache' => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          protected 'customData' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      protected 'reasonPhrase' => string 'Bad Request' (length=11)
      protected 'statusCode' => int 400
```

Somebody have a real example of copyObject to another bucket?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I had looked at the documentation but I did not quite understand how to configure the "source" and "destination", but now I understand. Thanks!

```
  $response = $s3->copyObject(
        array(
            'Bucket' => 'DESTINATION BUCKET',
            'Key' => 'DESTINATION OBJECT KEY',
            'CopySource' => urlencode('SOURCE BUCKET' . '/' . 'SOURCE OBJECT KEY')
        )
    );
```

Comment: What is the "DESTINATION OBJECT KEY"

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the example in the docs?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_copyObject

Answer (score 0):

To copy object from one bucket to another follow the steps:
`    require "vendor/autoload.php";
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

```
$s3Client = new S3Client([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'us-west-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
 ]);

$DestinationBucketFolderName = "NewFolder1";
$sourceBucket = '*** Your Source Bucket Name ***';
$sourceKeyname = '*** Your Source Object Key / Object Name That Are 
Stored On Source Bucket ***';
$targetBucket = '*** Your Target Bucket Name / Destination Bucket 
Name ***';

// Copy an object.
 $s3Client->copyObject([
      'Bucket'     => $targetBucket,
      'Key'        => " 
      {$DestinationBucketFolderName}/{$sourceKeyname}",
      'CopySource' => "{$sourceBucket}/{$sourceKeyname}"
]);
```

`

and refer the documentation of AWS sdk-3 for php
documentation link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/php-s3-s3-copying-objects.php.html